# Last flight cancelled compensation

Tags: usa, domestic-travel, delta-air-lines

I was flying domestic with Delta last Friday. Boarding was done before pilot noticed the flat tire. Estimated repair time was 4 hours. I had a connection in ATL and there was no way I could make that because it was the last flight out of ATL for the day. Delta offered for passengers to wait 4 hours till they repair or reschedule to a later flight for no extra fee.
I got my trip rescheduled to the first flight the following Saturday morning because I didn't want to get stuck in ATL that night.
Question: Am I entitled to any other compensation due to their delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retroactively, most probably no*.  If were not based at the origin, you maybe could have gotten accommodations and meals since it was a mechanical failure.  In that case, they might have preferred you take the original flight and overnight in ATL.

*While not 'compensation' in the same class as Europe, it is common for customers in such situations to get some miles bonused to their account by writing to Customer Service.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow up with Customer Service and see what they say.

Comment: Almost a full month after the date of travel, Delta responded with 9500 bonus SkyMiles credit to the account. Thanks @johns-305 for the answer.